# How do you get Sentry.io to include form post information in their exception reportings

Tags: asp.net-core, sentry

I use Sentry.io to get reports of server-side exceptions from my aspnetcore 7.0 side project production environment, but I can't figure out how to get Sentry to include the form post information that would allow me to actually see what data was inputted that caused the exception.

Does any one know how to change this? Or should I just Honeycomb for tracking API calls, and then when I see a Sentry exception I can find the details in Honeycomb (which I'm also having trouble setting up!)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Adding Context](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/enriching-events/context/):

You can do something like this when an exception happens to add the user data to the transaction:

```cs
using Sentry;

SentrySdk.ConfigureScope(scope =>
{
    scope.Contexts["character"] = new
    {
        Name = "Mighty Fighter",
        Age = 19,
        AttackType = "melee"
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! Would it be wrong just to add my whole PageModel to this context?

Comment: There are [Size Limitations](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/enriching-events/context/#size-limitations) that you should consider. I'd suggest only sending the necessary data.